# mediawiki 1.16.5: Load javascript for a specific namespace

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I am developing an extension for Mediawiki which is based on another extension (developed in-house) that will not work above with a Mediawiki installation with a version superior 1.16.5 . I need to include javascript in pages belonging to a specific namespace and I cannot use the `ResourceLoader` http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader .

Does someone know if there's a simple to do this? I need to include JQuery and Datatables for a custom rendering of the pages belonging to the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three ways to go about this.

The 1st approach is to edit the magic page `MediaWiki:Common.js` and add something like this:

```
if(wgNamespaceNumber == 0) { // NS_MAIN
  importScript('MediaWiki:MyScript.js');
}
```

You can place arbitrary javascript in the block, the `importScript` bit there is for executing JavaScript stored in a Wiki page but there are other ways to include JS on the fly as well (see eg. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)).  See [Manual:Interface/JavaScript](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript) for details of the MediaWiki side of things.

The 2nd approach would be to hack the PHP that produces the MediaWiki page to inject `<script>` tags depending on the current namespace, but that's a bit more involved: you'd need to build a custom extension and hook it in at some appropriate point.  The ParserAfterTidy hook looks suitable, see [Hooks](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks).

The 3rd approach would be to simply edit the skin and load the JS for every page in the wiki -- is there a reason you don't want to do this for every page?  They're cached anyway, so it's only a one-time hit.

Comment: Thank you. That's the kind of answer I was looking for. I will go for the `MediaWiki:Common.js` approach. Thanks for the link too!